# Dispatch an action in background app refresh with react native

Tags: react-native, redux

I'm using `react-native-background-fetch` to receive app refresh events and have been struggling to dispatch an action (that fetches data) when it's triggered. I'm able to do this outside of redux but not when I dispatch the action.

```
BackgroundFetch.configure({
  stopOnTerminate: false
}, async () => {
  await store.dispatch(getItemsAction);
  BackgroundFetch.finish();
});
```

Action:

```
export function getItemsAction() {
  // <-- Reaches here
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    // <-- But not here
    const items = await findAll();
    dispatch(itemsRetrieved(items));
  }
}
```

If not a solution, I'd like to get some insight into what's happening here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to call action creator

```
await store.dispatch(getItemsAction());
```

Then you'll need a middleware to handle functions as actions. I assume you are aware of `redux-thunk`.

Comment: Yeah, above is only a snippet.Missed out the parenthesis. Always helps to have another pair of eyes, thanks.

Comment: @sooper Then the second part. Have you added a middleware to handle functions (`redux-thunk` )?

Comment: Yes, I've been using `redux-thunk`, it's just not apparent in the code above. The issue was the parenthesis that was missing.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a headless task running in the background, It does not have access to the redux store from what I experienced.

You will want to use something like AsyncStorage (https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage) when running the task as headless js, which is what happens when the app is running background events.